# ggplot2: Overlay two plots and use both legends

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been building this rather involved plotting function which constructs a big graphic panel many plots and layers, the most recent addition to the stack of challenges has been to produce plots with a secondary scale. To this end, I have the following support function, which gets called from the outside with valid ggplot2 objects...

```
overlap_plots <- function(base_plt, over_plt) {

    plot_theme <- function(p) {
        plyr::defaults(p$theme, theme_get())
    }

    base_g = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(base_plt))
    overlay_g = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(over_plt))

    plt_panel = c(subset(base_g$layout, name == "panel", se = t:r))
    pnl_ind = which(overlay_g$layout$name == "panel")
    leg_ind = which(overlay_g$layout$name == "guide-box") 
    final_grob = gtable_add_grob(base_g,
            overlay_g$grobs[[pnl_ind]],
            plt_panel$t,
            plt_panel$l,
            plt_panel$b,
            plt_panel$l)

    final_grob = gtable_add_grob(final_grob,
            overlay_g$grobs[[leg_ind]],
            plt_panel$t,
            plt_panel$l,
            plt_panel$b,
            plt_panel$l)
    return(final_grob)
}
```

However, the second call to gtable_add_grob() doesn't actually seem to be doing anything...

For the sake of reproducability here are two random plots...

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gtable)

d = data.frame(Time = as.POSIXct(seq(1446871740, 1446893340, 60), origin = "1970-01-01"), Value = rnorm(361))
base_plt = ggplot() + geom_line(data=d, aes(Time, d[, 2], color="#F564E3")) + 
        scale_color_manual(values = "#F564E3", labels = "#F564E3") +
        theme(
                plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0), 'cm'),
                legend.position = c(0, 1),
                legend.justification = c(0.1, .9))
b = data.frame(Time = as.POSIXct(seq(1446871740, 1446893340, 60), origin = "1970-01-01"), Value = rnorm(361))
over_plt = ggplot() + geom_line(data=d, aes(Time, b[, 2], color="#00C094")) + 
        scale_color_manual(values = "#00C094", labels = "#00C094") +
        theme(
                legend.position = c(0, 0),
                legend.justification = c(0.1, 0.1),
                panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
                panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

g = overlap_plots(base_plt, over_plt)

grid.draw(g)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question might have been answered before, but I can't find it in a hurry.

When you add a grob using `gtable_add_grob()`, and you do not assign a name, gtable assigns a default name, "layout". But, in your function, that means two grobs in the one cell with the same name. gtable does not like it, and only the first is drawn. Give them different names:

```
overlap_plots <- function(base_plt, over_plt) {

    plot_theme <- function(p) {
        plyr::defaults(p$theme, theme_get())
    }

    base_g = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(base_plt))
    overlay_g = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(over_plt))

    plt_panel = c(subset(base_g$layout, name == "panel", se = t:r))
    pnl_ind = which(overlay_g$layout$name == "panel")
    leg_ind = which(overlay_g$layout$name == "guide-box") 
    final_grob = gtable_add_grob(base_g,
            overlay_g$grobs[[pnl_ind]],
            plt_panel$t,
            plt_panel$l,
            plt_panel$b,
            plt_panel$r, name = "a")

    final_grob = gtable_add_grob(final_grob,
            overlay_g$grobs[[leg_ind]],
            plt_panel$t,
           plt_panel$l,
           plt_panel$b,
           plt_panel$r, name = "b")
    return(final_grob)
}
```